# javascript switch case not working with email id as value

Tags: javascript

I have a simple switch case which will take the email id of the person and test for the password. As of now, I am hardcoding the values. My problem is that when I use the user name, the switch case works fine but when I try the same with email id, it does not call the required function. What is wrong? Code is below:

```
switch(uname){
    case "":if(pass == ""){ alert("Please enter you credentials!!");}
        break;
    case "test@abc.com": if(pass == "test123"){ NavigateToDash(); }
                 else{alert("Wrong Credentials!! Please re-enter!!");}
                 break;
    case "admin@abc.com": if(pass == "admin123"){ NavigateToAdmin(); }
                  else{alert("Wrong Credentials!! Please re-enter!!")}
                  break;
    default: alert("Something is wrong!! contact admin");
}
```

`uname` is being set on a button click in a html page.

The function `NavigateToDash()` is not getting called. If I use just `test` instead of `test@abc.com`, this code works fine. Please tell me where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

adding the function which passes the `uname` to the `switch` statement:

```
function setValues(){
      uname = document.getElementById('user').value;
      pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
      window.localStorage.setItem('user', uname);
      window.localStorage.setItem('pass', pass);
}
```

in the function with `switch`, I am calling this function `setValues` first. Currently everything is being done locally.

Comment: Can you show the code that passes the `uname` to your switch? Sounds like something is going wrong there. Also.. logging a user in with just JS to check the credentials is not a good idea.

Comment: This is just a test code for initial testing. I will be connecting to a database with the credentials at a later stage.

Comment: *"If I use just test instead of test@abc.com, this code works fine."* Then that says that the `uname` variable doesn't contain the `@abc.com` part. *"Please tell me where I am wrong."* You're testing for a value that isn't present. We can't help you without more information, but really, this is just a case of using the fully-featured debugger built into your browser to see what's going on.

Comment: When I alert or console.log the `uname`, I am getting the value with the `@abc.com`. It is only in the switch case that the value is not being considered

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem. Without that you leave everyone guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I is working nicely here....problem may be in your inner functions.Also problem may be due to spaces in values..so use `trim()` function.see here for more http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
uname = document.getElementById('user').value);
pass = document.getElementById('password').value);
var u = uname.trim();
var p = pass.trim();
test(u,p);

function test(uname,pass){

switch(uname){
    case "":if(pass == ""){ alert("Please enter you credentials!!");}
        break;
    case "test@abc.com": if(pass == "test123"){ hello(); }
                 else{alert("Wrong Credentials!! Please re-enter!!");}
                 break;
    case "admin@abc.com": if(pass == "admin123"){ hello(); }
                  else{alert("Wrong Credentials!! Please re-enter!!")}
                  break;
    default: alert("Something is wrong!! contact admin");
}
}

function hello(){
alert('hello');
}
</script>
```